# Audio Routing in tinyAlsa

Tags: android, routes, codec, tinyalsa, audio-route

We are working on Custom Board having Audio Codec, AM/FM Tuner, BT Headset, BT Classic all controlled by I2S peripheral. We wants to route audio from BT Classic to Audio Codec, BT Classic to BT headset and so on.

We were planning to have seperate threads for connecting 2 audio devices. In application space, we will provide seperate device IDs which will indicate what device should play the Audio.

I needs to know how we can create a thread interlinking 2 audio devices? Also, is there any other ways to route various audio devices output to another audio devices?

Answer (score 0):

```
    BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getProfileProxy(this, mScanCallback, BluetoothProfile.A2DP);

    BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener mScanCallback = new BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(int profile, BluetoothProfile proxy) {
        if (profile == BluetoothProfile.A2DP) {
            proxy.getConnectedDevices().forEach(device -> {
                if (selectedDevice1 != null
                        && selectedDevice1.getDeviceMAC().equalsIgnoreCase(device.getAddress())) {
                    try {
                        Class clazz = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothA2dp");
                        Method method = clazz.getMethod("setActiveDevice", BluetoothDevice.class);
                        method.invoke(proxy, device);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("TEST", "", e);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(int i) {
    }
};
```